# Optimize a Group By that is done on a joined table in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, database-performance, sql-data-warehouse

I've been working at optimizing a query that I've been given, I'm curious if there is any way to speed up the following query that I have.

This isn't the exact query that I am using but I think it serves to show what I am working with.

(I'm using a data warehouse for the following)

```
SELECT sum(a), b, c, d FROM
(

SELECT a, tb.b, tc.c, td.d FROM table_a ta
LEFT JOIN table_b tb on ta.g = tb.g
LEFT JOIN table_c tc on ta.f = tc.f
LEFT JOIN table_d td on ta.e = td.e 

) as table

GROUP BY b, c, d
```

I have the inner query quite optimized so I don't think there is any issue there, the problem is when I attempt a group by on these values it slows down quite significantly, I'm pretty sure the query is having trouble distributing the work on the group by clause since nothing is indexed within the sub query.

Any suggestions?

[image: execution plan]

Comment: For optimisation questions you need to provide the execution plan, using Paste The Plan. And you typically can't simplify the query if you are wanting performance advice, because performance is very specific to the exact query.

Comment: Syntactically don't see why you need the second select.  Looks like it could all be done in the inline view.  Not much of a gain from that though...  Missing Indexes table sizes partitions if too "Big" but all guesses w/o Execution plans.

Comment: Note that grouping introduces a sort that isn't necessary with just the join. Try to see if your inner query suffers the same problem on its own if you say `ORDER BY b, c, d`. Sounds like there are indexes there that support the joins, but nothing to help with sorting.

Comment: I've added a copy of the execution plan that compute to control node is the issue

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've added an order by in my inner select, it does seem to be the case that attempting a sort causes an issue for the query, how would i implement an index that can support this query given the sort will be across columns from the different given tables?

Comment: I don't know, `compute to control node` tells me you're out of SQL Server and into some other kind-of-related product.

Comment: @AaronBertrand this is a SQL Data Warehouse hosted in Azure

Comment: Right, and technically that’s not SQL Server so that tag should probably not be there.